# .NET Attributes prioritize on different targets

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, attributes

I've got a controller class which contains an attribute above it which logs system events.

the problem is that some of my methods in the controller contains sensitive data which i don't want to be saved in logs (such as passwords).

i tried to add a boolean property to the attribute which should signal to me if specific method contains sensitive data, and call the attribute on the method target (same attribute i used for the class target, just with the flag turned on) but it appears that the attribute above the class target is the one who has "priority" which means my sensitive data flag is always false.

does anyone knows how to make my method target override the class target when used above specific methods?

adding example for code here:

```
public class SystemEventAtt : Attribute {

public bool ContainsSensitiveData{ get; set; }

***
some additional code which logs stuff..
***

}

[SystemEventAtt]
public class SomeController : Controller {


[Route("someRoute")]
[SystemEventAtt(ContainsSensitiveData = true)]
[HttpPost]

public SomeObj FuncWhichContainsSensitiveData([FromBody] SomeOtherObj obj){

..some code
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> does anyone knows how to make my method target override the class target when used above specific methods?

If you want to only use `SystemEventAtt` attribute I think the answer is no.

Why don't you just add use attribute to your expectation writing log action?

Or there is another way.

You can create one attribute to represent you want to write log, and you can use reflection in `SystemEventAtt` attribute to get the action whether mark `WriteLog` attribute instead of use `bool`

```
public class WriteLogAttribute : Attribute {

}


public class SystemEventAtt : Attribute {

    ***
    some additional code which logs stuff..
    using reflection to get WriteLogAttribute check whether write log
    ***

}
```